# javascript - get date format like in php?

Tags: javascript, string, datetime

```php
<?php echo date('d M Y'); ?>
```

Result: `29 Sep 2019`

So easy, so elegant!

Seems there is no similar method to do this in javascript?

My try:

```js
let d = new Date();

console.log(d.getDate() + ' ' + (d.getMonth()+1) + ' ' + d.getFullYear());
```

Result: `29 9 2019`

But I need short month name instead of integer.

And yes, I saw many solutions *using library* or *creating an array of months names*, but I'm interested - **is there any native and core javascript way?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };

let date = new Date()

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US',options))
```

Comment: result - `Sep 29, 2019`

Comment: @qadenza this is dependent on locale specified, use `en-GB` for `29 Sep 2019`

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way.

You have to manually implement a such feature if you don't want to use a library:

```js
const months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
const d=new Date()

console.log(`${d.getDate()} ${months[d.getMonth()]} ${d.getFullYear()}`);
//29 Sep 2019
```

Or, try to use `.toLocaleString()`, but its return value is implementation-dependent.

Comment: what does it mean - `implementation-dependent` ?

Comment: That it isn't written in the ECMAScript standard, and maybe return different value in different browsers/JS-engines

Comment: @qadenza That it isn't written in the ECMAScript standard, and maybe return different value in different browsers/JS-engines

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
const date = new Date();
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'
}).replace(/ /g, '-');
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the moment.js library to do this.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

```
moment().format("D MMM YYYY")
```